# Help identify this movie about an old woman and an apparent delinquent

Tags: identify-this-movie

I believe this movie was from between the 60s and the 90s, but can't be certain. It involved an old woman visiting a facility of sorts, bringing pound cake to a troubled young man who was left there by his father. This same young man escapes with another young man, and ends up at the old woman's house, claiming they were let out on vacation or something similar. Obviously she knows the truth, but allows him to stay with her while he hides from the police.

Scenes I remember:

- She made biscuits with honey
- Near the end, she has friends/family over, and bangs a pan on the counter. Thinking it was a gunshot, the boy darts under the table, to the confusion of the others.
- The police find the boy, and when the old woman goes to get him, he has changed into red pajamas and is crying on his bed
- The old woman pushed him into a lake while teaching him to swim, standing on a dock while moving her legs and waving her arms in a circle. Another couple notices this (not seeing the boy) and make remarks about her finally losing it/going crazy.
- I believe she had a garden as well, and a special method involving "little treasures" and/or talking to the plants to help them grow better. Her garden was amazing.

Answer (score 7):

Possibly [Walking Across Egypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walking_Across_Egypt) from 1999, based on a novel by the same name.

> **The film follows the life of Mattie Rigsbee (Ellen Burstyn), an elderly woman who believes in strong religious convictions.** [...] Mattie soon finds a likable friend in the local dogcatcher, Lamar Benfield (Mark Hamill). It is through this relationship in which **she meets the dogcatcher's nephew, a troubled, foul-mouthed, orphaned juvenile delinquent, Wesley (Jonathan Taylor Thomas), currently serving time in juvenile detention for a recent car theft. Mattie finds that this young man is just missing direction** and believes that with a little insight on Christianity he can straighten up and fly right.

At some point she pushes him into a lake to teach him to swim, which you can see here around 1:54: